# Change line colour in Excel 2007 chart series

Tags: c#, charts, excel-2007, excel-interop

First of all, I've looked at EVERY other post here, about this (I think) and none of them solves it.

I have a graph in excel, where I would like to change the colour of the line. It seems like, everything in the series line settings, is out of reach. If I cannot set the colour, I would like to set the fill to none, so the line is invisible, only showing the markers, which I can manipulate.

However, fill is also in the colour settings.

I have tried recording a macro aswell, but it shows nothing, other than series select.

Other posts here, suggest setting border on the series, but there is no border object to my knowledge.

Does anyone have any tricks that might solve this?

Comment: how do you acces excel, through c# code? (based on your tag)

Comment: @Moonlight, With Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code you've, i.e., c# that selects the series.  Is the chart in a regular worksheet or a chart sheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, over on the MSDN forums, Andrei Smolin managed to solve it for me.
It was indeed Series.Border that fixed it.

The big problem was, that Border does not show up, as an object on series. Not even in VBA.
It seems to be fixed in Excel 2010, but this is the behaviour i'm experiencing in 2007 SP3.

So, the solution was to simply type:

```
MSExcel.Series Series1 = (MSExcel.Series)Chart.SeriesCollection(1);
Series1.Border.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 129, 189));
```

which compiled fine, and worked at runtime.

For reference sake, this is the MSDN thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/2816660e-a18e-47f4-b121-02a71cb2c262

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nicolai's answer, there is an easier way to pass color value to Border.Color, for example:

```
    Series1.Border.Color = (int) XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Answer (score -2):

For Excel 2007, the following:

`series5.Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(80, 208, 146).ToArgb();`

works for me.